# No validation other than Required working for my test method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, unit-testing, testing

I am creating a test method in Asp.Net MVC 5. I am using following code to test my registration method

```
[TestMethod]
    public async Task Registration_Test_For_Password_And_Confirm_Password_Mismatch()
    {

        // Arrange
        var registerationModel = new RegisterViewModel() { UserName = "abc", Password = null, ConfirmPassword = "jjk", Email = "nitin.daiya@sunarctechnologies.com" };

        // Validate model state start
        var validationContext = new ValidationContext(registerationModel, null, null);
        Validator.TryValidateObject(registerationModel, validationContext, validationResults);
        foreach (var validationResult in validationResults)
        {
            controller.ModelState.AddModelError(validationResult.MemberNames.First(), validationResult.ErrorMessage);
        }
        // Validate model state end

        // Act

        var result = await controller.Register(registerationModel) as ViewResult;

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual("", result.ViewName);
        Assert.IsFalse(controller.ModelState.IsValid);
    }
```

Above code is working fine if I pass empty values for the Required fields. 
If I try to check any other validation it is not showing the error message and test fails each time.

Following is my ViewModel

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [System.Web.Mvc.Remote("IsUserNameAvailable", "Account", ErrorMessage = "That UserName is already taken.")]
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [System.Web.Mvc.Remote("IsEmailAvailable", "Account", ErrorMessage = "That email is already taken.")]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

EDIT:  Solved the issue by changing `Validator.TryValidateObject(registerationModel, validationContext, validationResults);` to `Validator.TryValidateObject(registerationModel, validationContext, validationResults,true);` this. True is set for `validateAllProperties` property to check all validation.

It still not testing the remote validation. Any clue??

Comment: Not sure why you calling `validationResult.MemberNames.First()`? Should you be checking all the member names?

Comment: What should I use then? And I want to check all members for all validations, but I don't know how?

Comment: Not sure - haven't got time to test now, but within the foreach loop, may be it should be another loop - `foreach (var memberName in validationResult.MemberNames) { ...AddModelError(memberName, validationResult.ErrorMessage); }`

Comment: The `validationResult` contains errors only for `Required fields validation` in the list. But I want it to contain all the validation errors (for eg. StringLength, RegularExpression etc.) if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Validator.TryValidateObject(registerationModel, validationContext, validationResults)
```

This line will by default only validate required properties. To validate all properties, you need to set the validateAllProperties parameter to true:

```
Validator.TryValidateObject(registerationModel, validationContext, validationResults, true);
```

*(Adding this as it wasn't immediately clear that this question had an answer)*